# Transforming a column to have 10 Digits

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, csv

I have a csv file that contains phone numbers, some of them have 9 digits and some of them have 10. Is there a command that would allow the transformation of the column such that numbers that have only 9 digits will have a 0 appended in front of the numbers.

For example,

if the column has values "443332332" and "0441223332", I would like to have the value of the one with 9 digits changed to "0443332332"?

Sorry, I should have elaborated.

I was wondering if there was a command to do it in SQLlite easily? I prefer not to use excel to transform the column as if I can get it to working with sqllite it would be so much easier and faster.

Comment: what is the datatype of the column ?

Comment: Is this question is about CSV files why is it tagged with MySQL and SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generic solution would be:

```
select substr('0000000000'||'1234567', -10, 10) from table_name;
```

The above query would always return 10 digits and add leading zeroes to the missed out number of digits.

For example, the above query would return : **0001234567**

For Update, use

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET PHONE_NO = substr('0000000000'|| PHONE_NO, -10, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that just prepending a zero on strings with length 9 will work for your application, something simple will work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(phone_number) = 9 THEN '0'||phone_number
            ELSE phone_number
        END AS phone_number
  FROM your_table
;
```

You could also update the table, depending on your needs:

```
UPDATE your_table
   SET phone_number = '0'||phone_number
 WHERE LENGTH(phone_number) = 9
;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the .csv using Excel,
2. Add a filter to the column,
3. Sort from A-Z to get all the columns with 9 digits,

Then follow the steps here

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/keep-leading-zeros-in-number-codes-HA010342581.aspx